I am lost by the "Undefined Control Sequence" and the 'unnaligned' equations
[EDIT V.1]
Good day to all. I am new to LaTex and I have two problems:

The warning "Undefined Control Sequence," which doesn't really seem to bother the parsing (I'm doing it in Overleaf), because everything still parses. The warning starts from line 13 and it repeats for every \end{align} onwards. (It could probably be the main cause of the misalignment)
The \begin{align} \end{align} don't align in some parts. (They somehow don't center-align)

In this below picture, using the previous page number (2) as the benchmark for center-align, 'Contoh 6' clearly doesn't center-align except for the beginning.

In this below picture, it starts fine, but when starting from Untuk x < -1 it's not center-aligned anymore.

While for the picture below (Contoh 7), this is the smoothest one I can get.

I would really appreciate any pointers on what is happening, what I have done wrong, and/or how to fix these problems. Thank you very much.
Here's the full tex code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Math symbols such as \mathbb
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   % plots
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10.5in}]{geometry}

\title{Soal}
\author{Penulis }
\date{Juni 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

Contoh 1
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab}&\neq \frac{\cancel a+\cancel a \cancel b+\cancel bc}{\cancel a \cancel b}\\& \neq 1+c
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab} &=\frac{a}{ab}+\frac{ab}{ab}+\frac{bc}{ab}\tag{1}\\ & = \frac{1}{b}+1+\frac{c}{a}\tag{2}\\& = 1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{c}{a}\tag{3}
\end{align}
\\
Contoh 2
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)&= a+(-b^2)\tag{1}\\&= a-b^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)&=a+(-(-b)(-b))\tag{1}\\&=a+(-(b^2))\tag{2}\\&=a+(-b^2)\tag{3}\\&=a+(-1*b^2)\tag{4}\\&=a+(-1)(b^2)\tag{5}\\&=a-(1)(b^2)\tag{6}\\&=a-b^2\tag{7}
\end{align}

\newpage

Contoh 3
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}&\neq \frac{\cancel a - b^{\cancel 2}}{\cancel a - \cancel b}+\frac{\cancel a - \cancel b}{\cancel b - \cancel a}\tag{1}\\&\neq \frac{-b}{1}+1\tag{2}\\&\neq -b+1\tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{-(a-b)}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{\cancel {a-b}}{-\cancel {(a-b)}}\tag{2}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{1}{-1}\tag{3}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+(-1)\tag{4}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}-1\tag{5}
\end{align}
\\
Contoh 4
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}&\neq \frac{a-c}{b-d}\tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}&=\frac{a*d-c*b}{bd}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}\tag{2}
\end{align}
\\
Contoh 4 Diputar balik (mirip contoh 1)
\begin{align}
    \frac{ad-bc}{bd}&=\frac{ad}{bd}-\frac{bc}{bd}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{a\cancel d}{b\cancel d}-\frac{\cancel bc}{\cancel bd}\tag{2}\\&=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\tag{3}
\end{align}

\newpage

Contoh 5
\begin{align}
    x+3&>0\\x&>-3\\\\\therefore{}L&=(-3;\infty)
\end{align}
\\
Contoh 6
\begin{align}
    x^2-5x-6&\ge0\\(x+1)(x-6)&\ge0
\end{align}
Jangan langsung dibuat $x \le -1$ atau $x \ge 6$, buat dulu kayak di bawah:
\begin{align*}
    x&=-1\\x&=6
    \clap{Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Habis itu cek apakah dengan x di sebelah kiri dan kanan 2 dan 3 pertidsaksamaan di atas akan valid
\begin{align*}
    \text{Untuk $x \le -1$}\\
    ((-2)^2)-5(-2)-6\ge0\\
    4+10-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\\\
    \text{Untuk $-1 \le x \le 6$}\\
    (0)^2-5(0)-6\ge0\\
    0-0-6\ge0\\
    -6\ge0\\\\
    \text{Untuk $x \ge 6$}\\
    (7^2)-5(7)-6\ge0\\
    49-35-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\\\
    \therefore L=(-\infty;-1)\lor(6;\infty)
\end{align*}

\newpage

Contoh 7
\begin{align*}
    |x+10|&=2x-3\\\\
    \clap{Bagian Satu: Positif}\\
    (+1)(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    +(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    (x+10)&=2x-3\\
    x+10&=2x-3\\   
    x+10-10&=2x-3-10\\
    x&=2x-13\\
    x-2x&=2x-2x-13\\
    -x&=-13\\
    x&=13\\\\
    \clap{Bagian Dua: Negatif}\\
    (-1)(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -x-10&=2x+3\\
    -x-10+10&=2x+3+10\\
    -x&=2x+13\\
    -x-2x&=2x+13-2x\\
    -3x&=13\\
    x&=\frac{13}{3}\\\\
    \therefore L&=\{13;\frac{13}{3}\}
\end{align*}

\newpage

Contoh 8
\begin{align*}
    |2x-5|&> x+8\\\\
    \clap{Bagian Satu: Positif}\\
    (2x-5)&=x+8\\
    2x-5-x&=x+8-x\\
    x-5&=8\\
    x-5+5&=8+5\\
    x&=13\\\\
    \clap{Bagian Dua: Negatif}\\
    -(2x-5)&=x+8\\
    -2x+5&=x+8\\
    -2x+5-x&=x+8-x\\
    -3x+5&=8\\
    -3x+5-5&=8-5\\
    -3x&=3\\
    \frac{-3x}{-3}&=\frac{3}{-3}\\
    x&=-1\\
    \clap{Artinya, x = -1 dan x = 13 adalah garis batas, tapi mereka tidak termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Pas diurain, ga langsung pake tanda $\ge$, tapi pake sama dengan dulu, baru sekarang kita tes:
\begin{align*}
    \clap{Untuk $x < -1$ (-1 tidak termasuk)}\\
    |2(-2)-5|&>(-2)+8\\
    |-4-5|&>6\\
    |-9|&>6\\
    9&>6\\\\
    \clap{Untuk $-1 < x < 13$}\\
    |2(0)-4|&>0+8\\
    |-4|&>8\\
    4&>8\\\\
    \clap{Untuk $x > 13$ (13 tidak termasuk)}\\
    |2(13)-4|&>13+8\\
    |26-4|&>21\\
    |22|&>21\\
    22&>21\\\\
    \clap{Seluruh x yang memenuhi pertidaksamaan di atas hanyalah $x < -1$ atau $x > 13$}\\\\
    \therefore L&=(\infty;-1)\lor(13;\infty)
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Now, I am going to give the revision version:

I have changed \\\\ to \\[\baselineskip].
I have changed the \\ where I want just an empty space/enter with \medskip.
I have inserted \noindent before all of my first word in each page.
I have, however, not changed clap{} to intertext{} due to visual reason. intertext{} makes my text hard to read (all got left-aligned), while with clap{} it serves well to what I want visually. Now, it's easy to follow along and easy to read.
I have commented A4 and resize the page instead (using simply total).

Page 5 looks like below (is what I want visually) :

The whole tex code is below:
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Math symbols such as \mathbb
% \usepackage{pgfplots}   % plots
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % , total={6.5in, 10in}
\usepackage{cancel}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\title{Problems}
\author{Penulis }
\date{Juni 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%\section*{Introduction}

\noindent
Contoh 1
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab}
    &\neq \frac{\cancel a+\cancel a \cancel b+\cancel bc}{\cancel a \cancel b}\\
    & \neq 1+c
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab} 
    &=\frac{a}{ab}+\frac{ab}{ab}+\frac{bc}{ab}\tag{1}\\ 
    & = \frac{1}{b}+1+\frac{c}{a}\tag{2}\\
    & = 1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{c}{a}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 2
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)
    &= a+(-b^2)\tag{1}\\
    &= a-b^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)&=a+(-(-b)(-b))\tag{1}\\
    &=a+(-(b^2))\tag{2}\\
    &=a+(-b^2)\tag{3}\\
    &=a+(-1*b^2)\tag{4}\\
    &=a+(-1)(b^2)\tag{5}\\
    &=a-(1)(b^2)\tag{6}\\
    &=a-b^2\tag{7}
\end{align}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 3
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}
    &\neq \frac{\cancel a - b^{\cancel 2}}{\cancel a - \cancel b}+\frac{\cancel a - \cancel b}{\cancel b - \cancel a}\tag{1}\\
    &\neq \frac{-b}{1}+1\tag{2}\\
    &\neq -b+1\tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{-(a-b)}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{\cancel {a-b}}{-\cancel {(a-b)}}\tag{2}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{1}{-1}\tag{3}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+(-1)\tag{4}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}-1\tag{5}
\end{align}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 4
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}
    &\neq \frac{a-c}{b-d}\tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align*}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}
    &=\frac{a*d-c*b}{bd}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 4 Diputar balik (mirip contoh 1)
\begin{align*}
    \frac{ad-bc}{bd}
    &=\frac{ad}{bd}-\frac{bc}{bd}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{a\cancel d}{b\cancel d}-\frac{\cancel bc}{\cancel bd}\tag{2}\\
    &=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 5
\begin{align*}
    x+3&>0\\
    x&>-3
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \therefore{}L=(-3;\infty)
\end{align*}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 6
\begin{align*}
    x^2-5x-6&\ge0\\
    (x+1)(x-6)&\ge0
\end{align*}
Jangan langsung dibuat $x \ge -1$ dan $x \ge 6$, buat dulu kayak di bawah:
\begin{align*}
    x&=-1\\
    x&=6\\
    \clap{Artinya, $x=-1$ dan $x=6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Habis itu cek apakah dengan x di sebelah kiri dan kanan dari $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ pertidsaksamaan di atas akan valid:
\begin{align*}
    \text{Untuk $x\le -1$}\\
    ((-2)^2)-5(-2)-6&\ge0\\
    4+10-6&\ge0\\
    8&\ge0\\[\baselineskip]
    \text{Untuk $-1\le x\le 6$}\\
    (0)^2-5(0)-6&\ge0\\
    0-0-6&\ge0\\
    -6&\ge0\\[\baselineskip]
    \text{Untuk $x\ge 6$}\\
    (7^2)-5(7)-6&\ge0\\
    49-35-6&\ge0\\
    8&\ge0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \therefore L=(-\infty;-1)\lor(6;\infty)
\end{align*}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 7
\begin{align*}
    |x+10|&=2x-3\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Bagian Satu: Positif}\\
    (+1)(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    +(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    (x+10)&=2x-3\\
    x+10&=2x-3\\   
    x+10-10&=2x-3-10\\
    x&=2x-13\\
    x-2x&=2x-2x-13\\
    -x&=-13\\
    x&=13\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Bagian Dua: Negatif}\\
    (-1)(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -x-10&=2x+3\\
    -x-10+10&=2x+3+10\\
    -x&=2x+13\\
    -x-2x&=2x+13-2x\\
    -3x&=13\\
    x&=\frac{13}{3}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \therefore L=\{13;\frac{13}{3}\}
\end{align*}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 8
\begin{align*}
    |2x-5|&> x+8\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Bagian Satu: Positif}\\
    (2x-5)&=x+8\\
    2x-5-x&=x+8-x\\
    x-5&=8\\
    x-5+5&=8+5\\
    x&=13\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Bagian Dua: Negatif}\\
    -(2x-5)&=x+8\\
    -2x+5&=x+8\\
    -2x+5-x&=x+8-x\\
    -3x+5&=8\\
    -3x+5-5&=8-5\\
    -3x&=3\\
    \frac{-3x}{-3}&=\frac{3}{-3}\\
    x&=-1\\
    \clap{Artinya, x = -1 dan x = 13 adalah garis batas, tapi mereka tidak termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Pas diurain, ga langsung pake tanda $\ge$, tapi pake sama dengan dulu, baru sekarang kita tes:
\begin{align*}
    |2x-5|&> x+8\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Untuk $x < -1$ ($-1$ tidak termasuk)}\\
    |2(-2)-5|&>(-2)+8\\
    |-4-5|&>6\\
    |-9|&>6\\
    9&>6\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Untuk $-1 < x < 13$}\\
    |2(0)-4|&>0+8\\
    |-4|&>8\\
    4&>8\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Untuk $x > 13$ (13 tidak termasuk)}\\
    |2(14)-4|&>14+8\\
    |28-4|&>22\\
    |24|&>22\\
    24&>22\\[\baselineskip]
    \clap{Seluruh x yang memenuhi pertidaksamaan di atas hanyalah $x < -1$ atau $x > 13$}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \therefore L&=(-\infty;-1)\lor(13;\infty)\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Welcome. // To localize your problem I suggest to make a copy of your file, and either delete or comment out (prefered way) useful chunks of code; in your case perhaps doing so pagewise is a good starting point. // If you deleted the problematic part, your file will compile. Revitalizing it, repeat this process, i.e. deactivate (as described) useful parts there. // Pay attention to the first (one or two) error messages.

Hello. Thank you. With your suggestion, I tackled my first problem: missing a \usepackage{cancel}. Now, I'm on to the next one.

Great :) // If you get stuck, try isolating the smallest amount of code which, when we compile it, will show your problem. Post a NEW question with it. Good luck

errors do bother the parsing: as you discovered even if you get a PDF at the end, its content and the output can be wrong. So never ignore a red number in overleaf.

if you get any error only use the pdf as a debugging aid, tex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document it makes no attempt to make usable pdf output after an error.

start with the simplest preamble you can do not add packages that you do not use.

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10.5in}]{geometry} makes no sense you are specifying the paper size is A4 (which is a standard size defined in millimeters) then specify its height and width in inches. the two settings are clearly contradictory.

\clap{Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.} this is specifying that you want it to overLAP the surrounding text, which is why you get the overprinting, is that what you intended?

Hello. Just want to give an update. So, the problems are solved, somehow.

I changed all \clap{...} in 'Contoh 6' to \text{...} and they center-aligned themselves.
I made a new block of \begin{align*} ... \end{align*} for all \therefore .... It fixes all the disalignment problems, seen very clearly in 'Contoh 6' and 'Contoh 8'
I rewrote the codes in 'Contoh 6' and 'Contoh 8' in Overleaf, because I copy-pasted them from Notion. It seems, that was the reason why they broke.

Thank you for all the helps.

@DavidCarlisle I just knew that those two settings (A4 and inches) are contradictory, will see them further.

@DavidCarlisle Regarding \clap{Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.} No, I don't have any intention in making it overLAP, I just wanted to make them center-aligned. They somehow do the trick, hence why I use them. I will further look on distinction between \text and \clap.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for the clarification. Now, there are no more red numbers showing.

It would be rather odd to have centered text but if you really want it use \intertext{\centering some text here} \clap is for overlapping things.

Hey, David. Thanks, again. The centered text is for in-block explanation, the rest is used for directives. Hence, the need.

Don't edit the question so much after answers posted it naked it very hard to read later. Heading edit v1 doesn't help people who don't see the original. Post a new question if you have a new question. But you should never need noindent and only use c lap if you want overlapping text

Gotcha. Didn't know about that. I'll see to it later. Anyway, I have what I want visually now and tried to use all of your recommendations, except the \intertext{}. I hope you can let it slide for now. Thanks again, all of you!

Only use packages that you need in the document, never use \\\\ and only use \clap if you want the content to over_lap_ the surrounding text.

See comments added inline in the document
\documentclass{article}
% not used \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
% not needed as you have mathtools \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Math symbols such as \mathbb
% not used \usepackage{amsthm}
% not used \usepackage{pgfplots}   % plots

% self contradictory \usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 10.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{cancel}% needed

\title{Soal}
\author{Penulis }
\date{Juni 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

Contoh 1
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab}&\neq \frac{\cancel a+\cancel a \cancel b+\cancel bc}{\cancel a \cancel b}\\& \neq 1+c
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab} &=\frac{a}{ab}+\frac{ab}{ab}+\frac{bc}{ab}\tag{1}\\ & = \frac{1}{b}+1+\frac{c}{a}\tag{2}\\& = 1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{c}{a}\tag{3}
\end{align}
% no\\
Contoh 2
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)&= a+(-b^2)\tag{1}\\&= a-b^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)&=a+(-(-b)(-b))\tag{1}\\&=a+(-(b^2))\tag{2}\\&=a+(-b^2)\tag{3}\\&=a+(-1*b^2)\tag{4}\\&=a+(-1)(b^2)\tag{5}\\&=a-(1)(b^2)\tag{6}\\&=a-b^2\tag{7}
\end{align}

\newpage

Contoh 3
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}&\neq \frac{\cancel a - b^{\cancel 2}}{\cancel a - \cancel b}+\frac{\cancel a - \cancel b}{\cancel b - \cancel a}\tag{1}\\&\neq \frac{-b}{1}+1\tag{2}\\&\neq -b+1\tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{-(a-b)}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{\cancel {a-b}}{-\cancel {(a-b)}}\tag{2}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{1}{-1}\tag{3}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+(-1)\tag{4}\\&=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}-1\tag{5}
\end{align}
% no\\
Contoh 4
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}&\neq \frac{a-c}{b-d}\tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}&=\frac{a*d-c*b}{bd}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}\tag{2}
\end{align}
% no\\
Contoh 4 Diputar balik (mirip contoh 1)
\begin{align}
    \frac{ad-bc}{bd}&=\frac{ad}{bd}-\frac{bc}{bd}\tag{1}\\&=\frac{a\cancel d}{b\cancel d}-\frac{\cancel bc}{\cancel bd}\tag{2}\\&=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\tag{3}
\end{align}

\newpage

Contoh 5
\begin{align}
  x+3&>0\\x&>-3\\% never use \\\\
  \therefore{}L&=(-3;\infty)
\end{align}
% never use \\ after align \\
Contoh 6
\begin{align}
    x^2-5x-6&\ge0\\(x+1)(x-6)&\ge0
\end{align}
Jangan langsung dibuat $x \le -1$ atau $x \ge 6$, buat dulu kayak di bawah:
\begin{align*}
  x&=-1\\x&=6\\
  % no \clap
    \intertext{\centering Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Habis itu cek apakah dengan x di sebelah kiri dan kanan 2 dan 3 pertidsaksamaan di atas akan valid
\begin{align*}
    \text{Untuk $x \le -1$}\\
    ((-2)^2)-5(-2)-6\ge0\\
    4+10-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\% no\\
    \intertext{\centering Untuk $-1 \le x \le 6$}
    (0)^2-5(0)-6\ge0\\
    0-0-6\ge0\\
    -6\ge0\\% no\\
    \intertext{Untuk $x \ge 6$}\\
    (7^2)-5(7)-6\ge0\\
    49-35-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\% \\
    \therefore L=(-\infty;-1)\lor(6;\infty)
\end{align*}

\newpage

Contoh 7
\begin{align*}
    |x+10|&=2x-3\\% no \\
    % no
  \intertext{\centering Bagian Satu: Positif}
    (+1)(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    +(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    (x+10)&=2x-3\\
    x+10&=2x-3\\   
    x+10-10&=2x-3-10\\
    x&=2x-13\\
    x-2x&=2x-2x-13\\
    -x&=-13\\
    x&=13\\% no\\
    \intertext{\centering Bagian Dua: Negatif}
    (-1)(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -x-10&=2x+3\\
    -x-10+10&=2x+3+10\\
    -x&=2x+13\\
    -x-2x&=2x+13-2x\\
    -3x&=13\\
    x&=\frac{13}{3}\\% no\\
    \therefore L&=\{13;\frac{13}{3}\}
\end{align*}

\newpage

Contoh 8
\begin{align*}
    |2x-5|&> x+8\\%\\
    \intertext{\centering Bagian Satu: Positif}
    (2x-5)&=x+8\\
    2x-5-x&=x+8-x\\
    x-5&=8\\
    x-5+5&=8+5\\
    x&=13\\%\\
    \intertext{\centering Bagian Dua: Negatif}
    -(2x-5)&=x+8\\
    -2x+5&=x+8\\
    -2x+5-x&=x+8-x\\
    -3x+5&=8\\
    -3x+5-5&=8-5\\
    -3x&=3\\
    \frac{-3x}{-3}&=\frac{3}{-3}\\
    x&=-1\\
    \intertext{\centering Artinya, x = -1 dan x = 13 adalah garis batas, tapi mereka tidak termasuk.}
\end{align*}
Pas diurain, ga langsung pake tanda $\ge$, tapi pake sama dengan dulu, baru sekarang kita tes:
\begin{align*}
    \intertext{\centering Untuk $x < -1$ (-1 tidak termasuk)}
    |2(-2)-5|&>(-2)+8\\
    |-4-5|&>6\\
    |-9|&>6\\
    9&>6\\%\\
    \intertext{\centering Untuk $-1 < x < 13$}
    |2(0)-4|&>0+8\\
    |-4|&>8\\
    4&>8\\%no\\
    \intertext{\centering Untuk $x > 13$ (13 tidak termasuk)}
    |2(13)-4|&>13+8\\
    |26-4|&>21\\
    |22|&>21\\
    22&>21\\%\\
    \intertext{\centering Seluruh x yang memenuhi pertidaksamaan di atas hanyalah $x < -1$ atau $x > 13$}
    \therefore L&=(\infty;-1)\lor(13;\infty)
\end{align*}
\end{document}


Hey! Thank you for showing the code, I have copy-pasted it to my Overleaf and took a good look. It helped me. Anyway, first question: Why is it a taboo to write \\\\\? I usually use double enters for distinguishing one context from another (in this case from different problems or [for x <= 1 then ... -> double enters ->  for x > 3 then ...]).  The second one is: I usually work in Word and use A4 size in inches. Why is it a taboo for using inches in managing the total size of the A4 paper? I mean, any practical reason/concern? Cheers!

It is not so much the units but the fact that you specify it at all. If you specify A4 paper then that has specified the height and width of the paper. If you specify the height and width again either you specify exactly the ISO standard size, which means that the new setting will do nothing, or you specify a different size which means the size is no longer ISO A4 size so the first setting is pointless.  do you want A4 size paper or 6in by 10.5in size paper? you can not possibly have both at the same time.

\\\\  is wrong as it is not adding vertical space, it is adding a line of the display with no content, it would for example not be discarded at a page break as tex thinks it is a formula not white space. Use \\[\baselineskip] to have an extra space after a line

My main recommendation is that you replace all instances of \clap with \intertext, a macro provided by the amsmath package. No need for \\\\ either before or after the \intertext instructions; actually, don't provide \\ after \intertext either.
Do be sure to load the cancel package, though.
The following screenshots show the first and fifth/final page of the full output of your modified code.





\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%\usepackage{amsmath}  %% 'amsmath' is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Math symbols such as \mathbb
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   % plots
\usepackage[a4paper, %total={6in, 10.5in}
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{cancel} %            <-- new
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel} % <-- new

\title{Soal}
\author{Penulis}
\date{Juni 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

Contoh 1
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab}
    &\neq \frac{\cancel{a}+\cancel{a} \cancel{b}+\cancel{b}c}{\cancel{a} \cancel{b}}\\
    & \neq 1+c
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a+ab+bc}{ab} 
    &=\frac{a}{ab}+\frac{ab}{ab}+\frac{bc}{ab}\tag{1}\\ 
    & = \frac{1}{b}+1+\frac{c}{a}\tag{2}\\
    & = 1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{c}{a}\tag{3}
\end{align}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 2
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)
    &= a+(-b^2)\tag{1}\\
    &= a-b^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    a+(-(-b)^2)
    &=a+(-(-b)(-b))\tag{1}\\
    &=a+(-(b^2))\tag{2}\\
    &=a+(-b^2)\tag{3}\\
    &=a+(-1\cdot b^2)\tag{4}\\
    &=a+(-1)(b^2)\tag{5}\\
    &=a-(1)(b^2)\tag{6}\\
    &=a-b^2\tag{7}
\end{align}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 3
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}
    &\neq \frac{\cancel{a} - b^{\cancel 2}}{\cancel{a} - \cancel{b}}
         +\frac{\cancel{a} - \cancel{b}}{\cancel{b} - \cancel{a}}\tag{1}\\
    &\neq \frac{-b}{1}+1\tag{2}\\
    &\neq -b+1\tag{3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{b-a}
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{a-b}{-(a-b)}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{\cancel {a-b}}{-\cancel {(a-b)}}\tag{2}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+\frac{1}{-1}\tag{3}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}+(-1)\tag{4}\\
    &=\frac{a-b^2}{a-b}-1\tag{5}
\end{align}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 4
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}
    &\neq \frac{a-c}{b-d}    \tag{1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}
    &=\frac{a\cdot d-c\cdot b}{bd}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}            \tag{2}
\end{align}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 4 Diputar balik (mirip contoh 1)
\begin{align}
    \frac{ad-bc}{bd}
    &=\frac{ad}{bd}-\frac{bc}{bd}\tag{1}\\
    &=\frac{a\cancel{d}}{b\cancel{d}}-\frac{\cancel{b}c}{\cancel{b}d}\tag{2}\\
    &=\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\tag{3}
\end{align}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 5
\begin{align}
    x+3&>0\\
    x&>-3\\[\jot]
    \therefore{}L
    &=(-3;\infty)
\end{align}

\medskip\noindent
Contoh 6
\begin{align}
    x^2-5x-6 &\ge0\\
    (x+1)(x-6) &\ge0
\end{align}

Jangan langsung dibuat $x \le -1$ atau $x \ge 6$, buat dulu kayak di bawah:
\begin{align*}
    x&=-1\\
    x&=6
\intertext{Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 6$ adalah garis batas dan mereka termasuk.}
\end{align*}

Habis itu cek apakah dengan x di sebelah kiri dan kanan 2 dan 3 pertidsaksamaan di atas akan valid
\begin{align*}
\intertext{Untuk $x \le -1$}%%\\
    ((-2)^2)-5(-2)-6\ge0\\
    4+10-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Untuk $-1 \le x \le 6$}%%\\
    (0)^2-5(0)-6\ge0\\
    0-0-6\ge0\\
    -6\ge0\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Untuk $x \ge 6$}%%\\
    (7^2)-5(7)-6\ge0\\
    49-35-6\ge0\\
    8\ge0\\[\jot]
    \therefore L=(-\infty;-1)\lor(6;\infty)
\end{align*}

\newpage
\noindent
Contoh 7
\begin{align*}
    |x+10|&=2x-3\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Bagian Satu: Positif}%%\\
    (+1)(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    +(x+10)&=2x-3\\
    (x+10)&=2x-3\\
    x+10&=2x-3\\   
    x+10-10&=2x-3-10\\
    x&=2x-13\\
    x-2x&=2x-2x-13\\
    -x&=-13\\
    x&=13\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Bagian Dua: Negatif}%%\\
    (-1)(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -(x+10)&=2x+3\\
    -x-10&=2x+3\\
    -x-10+10&=2x+3+10\\
    -x&=2x+13\\
    -x-2x&=2x+13-2x\\
    -3x&=13\\
    x&=\frac{13}{3}\\[\jot]
    \therefore L&=\left\{13;\frac{13}{3}\right\}
\end{align*}

\newpage

\noindent
Contoh 8
\begin{align*}
    |2x-5|&> x+8\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Bagian Satu: Positif}%%\\
    (2x-5)&=x+8\\
    2x-5-x&=x+8-x\\
    x-5&=8\\
    x-5+5&=8+5\\
    x&=13\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Bagian Dua: Negatif}%%\\
    -(2x-5)&=x+8\\
    -2x+5&=x+8\\
    -2x+5-x&=x+8-x\\
    -3x+5&=8\\
    -3x+5-5&=8-5\\
    -3x&=3\\
    \frac{-3x}{-3}&=\frac{3}{-3}\\
    x&=-1\\
\intertext{Artinya, $x = -1$ dan $x = 13$ adalah garis batas, tapi mereka tidak termasuk.}
\end{align*}

Pas diurain, ga langsung pake tanda $\ge$, tapi pake sama dengan dulu, baru sekarang kita tes:
\begin{align*}
\intertext{Untuk $x < -1$ (-1 tidak termasuk)}%%\\
    |2(-2)-5|&>(-2)+8\\
    |-4-5|&>6\\
    |-9|&>6\\
    9&>6\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Untuk $-1 < x < 13$}%%\\
    |2(0)-4|&>0+8\\
    |-4|&>8\\
    4&>8\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Untuk $x > 13$ (13 tidak termasuk)}%%\\
    |2(13)-4|&>13+8\\
    |26-4|&>21\\
    |22|&>21\\
    22&>21\\%%[1\baselineskip]
\intertext{Seluruh $x$ yang memenuhi pertidaksamaan di atas hanyalah $x < -1$ atau $x > 13$}%%\\%%[1\baselineskip]
    \therefore L&=(\infty;-1)\lor(13;\infty)\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}

